# Bluetooth app for android device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to develop an apk for an android device so that when i will push the apk in the device , it will make the bluetooth in ON state and as i dont have a blutooth headset ,I want my apk to automatically pair up with a virtual BT headset.

Can anyone help?? 
Any help will be appreciated .Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You got a lottt of work ahead of you..

btw, this is more for specific questions that have specific answers.  What you want is to build an app from scratch... try starting here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: actually i dont want any physical interaction with my device and the BT headset . I want my device to paired up without any BT headset.

Comment: How are you going to pair your device with a headset if you don't have a headset?

Comment: do i need to come here and ask questions if i have to simply pair a BT headset with a device